# Floating Animated Widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to implement something like the comment window in facebook-a floating widget that shadows the page underneath and animates itself to the screen and can contain a lot of content,maybe in a `ListView`.A search about the subject yielded mostly the use of `Stack` but creating for each 'Post' a stack widget and animating it myself seems really inefficient. where should I start?